# Background for <li> elements - child elements

Tags: html, css

I have menu like here https://jsfiddle.net/z93hy4gh/ .

```css
.widget li:hover {
    background:#002d5e;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget">
 <ul class="product-categories">
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-7 cat-parent current-cat-parent"><a href="http://strona.www/odzie/">Odzież </a>
    <ul class="children">
     <li class="cat-item cat-item-13"><a href="http://strona.www/odziez/bluzy-kolorowe-i-biale/">Bluzy białe</a></li>
     <li class="cat-item cat-item-14"><a href="http://strona.www/odziez/bluzy-100-bawelna/">Bluzy 100% bawełna</a></li>
     <li class="cat-item cat-item-22"><a href="http://strona.www/odziez/bluzy-na-trok/">Bluzy na trok</a></li>
     <li class="cat-item cat-item-32"><a href="http://strona.www/odziez/spodnie-kolorowe-i-biale/">Spodnie kolorowe i białe</a></li>
     <li class="cat-item cat-item-68"><a href="http://strona.www/odziez/spodnie-100-bawelna/">Spodnie 100% bawełna</a></li>
     <li class="cat-item cat-item-33 current-cat"><a href="http://strona.www/odziez/spodnie-biale/">Spodnie białe</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
   <li class="cat-item cat-item-43"><a href="http://strona.www/fartuch-/">Fartuch </a></li>
   <li class="cat-item cat-item-44"><a href="http://strona.www/fartuch-p/">Fartuch </a></li>
   <li class="cat-item cat-item-8"><a href="http://strona.www/obuwie/">Obuwie </a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I want to set background for hover elements. But I don't know how to set it for child elements. How can I use .cat-parent or .current-cat-parent class to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing a bit about what you want, but perhaps if you set the background color on the `a` elements, you can highlight each link without affecting a nested blocks of `li`'s.

I am assuming that you want to highlight the link text for each link in the lists.

```css
.widget .children li {
  background-color: yellow; /* demo only... */
  display: block;
}
.widget .children li:hover {
  background: pink;
}
.widget .product-categories > li:hover:not(:first-child) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.widget .product-categories > li:first-child a:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget">
  <ul class="product-categories">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-7 cat-parent current-cat-parent"><a href="http://strona.www/odzie/">Odzież </a>
      <ul class="children">
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-13"><a href="http://strona.www/odziez/bluzy-kolorowe-i-biale/">Bluzy białe</a></li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-14"><a href="http://strona.www/odziez/bluzy-100-bawelna/">Bluzy 100% bawełna</a></li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-22"><a href="http://strona.www/odziez/bluzy-na-trok/">Bluzy na trok</a></li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-32"><a href="http://strona.www/odziez/spodnie-kolorowe-i-biale/">Spodnie kolorowe i białe</a></li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-68"><a href="http://strona.www/odziez/spodnie-100-bawelna/">Spodnie 100% bawełna</a></li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-33 current-cat"><a href="http://strona.www/odziez/spodnie-biale/">Spodnie białe</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-43"><a href="http://strona.www/fartuch-/">Fartuch </a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-44"><a href="http://strona.www/fartuch-p/">Fartuch </a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-8"><a href="http://strona.www/obuwie/">Obuwie </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I do change link color too, but it's WP menu so unfortunately I need to edit background too ;/

Comment: The question is how do you want to display `<a href="http://strona.www/odzie/">Odzież </a>`, this link has a different mark-up than then others (not a single child element within a `li`).  Please explain in more detail.

Comment: @MarcinKusuah I made a minor modification, please see if it is closer to what you need.

Comment: I want to change background hover elements for <li> inside <ul class="children"> without changing hover for  <li class="cat-parent" > element and in the same time I want to have possibility to change hover for <li class="cat-parent" > ...

Comment: @MarcinKusuah I have something that is close, but I have trouble assigning distinct colors for the nested `li`'s versus the direct descendant `li`'s

Comment: Wow thanks. It works great, but... ;) anyway your code add background in Odzież not for <li> but for <a> and probably I'll try to add the same clases to a as to li and modify it a little bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `:not()` to prevent `.cat-parent`.

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('.cat-parent').click(
      function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('opened');
      });
  });
```

```css
.widget li:not(.opened):hover {
  background: #002d5e;
}
.children {
  display: none;
}
.opened .children {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget">
  <ul class="product-categories">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-7 cat-parent current-cat-parent"><a href="http://strona.www/odzie/">Odzież </a>
      <ul class="children">
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-13"><a href="http://strona.www/odziez/bluzy-kolorowe-i-biale/">Bluzy białe</a>
        </li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-14"><a href="http://strona.www/odziez/bluzy-100-bawelna/">Bluzy 100% bawełna</a>
        </li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-22"><a href="http://strona.www/odziez/bluzy-na-trok/">Bluzy na trok</a>
        </li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-32"><a href="http://strona.www/odziez/spodnie-kolorowe-i-biale/">Spodnie kolorowe i białe</a>
        </li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-68"><a href="http://strona.www/odziez/spodnie-100-bawelna/">Spodnie 100% bawełna</a>
        </li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-33 current-cat"><a href="http://strona.www/odziez/spodnie-biale/">Spodnie białe</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-43"><a href="http://strona.www/fartuch-/">Fartuch </a>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-44"><a href="http://strona.www/fartuch-p/">Fartuch </a>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-8"><a href="http://strona.www/obuwie/">Obuwie </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It works better than my code, but... Normally I have hidden <ul class="children"> , and after click it's showed. And in this case when I do the hover for Odzież element there is no background on it.. But I need it too

Comment: @MarcinKusuah Do you use jquery or javascript for opening `Odzież`?

Comment: nothing :) My WP theme redirect me to different site with open child submenu. But at the beginning there are cat-parent

Comment: Can you give me the link that which is shown your menu?

Comment: @MarcinKusuah Do you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/kpzf39eq/1/)?

Comment: Thanks man! But I can't add JS in this situation ;/ So finally I have to add background to <a> not to <li> and I turned out that this is possible